# tengo el objeto con Id y Nombre y por otro lado solo tengo los Id, como puedo hacer para comparar los Id iguales y que me imprima el name?

Tags: javascript

Este es el objeto:

```
Objeto [
    {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Action"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Animation"
    },
    {
        "id": 35,
        "name": "Comedy"
    },
    {
        "id": 80,
        "name": "Crime"
    },
    {
        "id": 99,
        "name": "Documentary"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Drama"
    },
    {
        "id": 10751,
        "name": "Family"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Fantasy"
    },
    {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "History"
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Horror"
    },
    {
        "id": 10402,
        "name": "Music"
    },
    {
        "id": 9648,
        "name": "Mystery"
    },
    {
        "id": 10749,
        "name": "Romance"
    },
    {
        "id": 878,
        "name": "Science Fiction"
    },
    {
        "id": 10770,
        "name": "TV Movie"
    },
    {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "id": 10752,
        "name": "War"
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "Western"
    }
]
```

Y este es el array:

```
Array (3) [14, 28, 35]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar [Filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) que te devolverá una lista de objetos filtrados según el criterio. Este criterio debería ser: sí existe el Id en el otro array, retorna true (esto se hace con [incluides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)).

Luego puedes recorrer los resultados e imprimir los names

```js
let Objeto = [
    {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Action"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Adventure"
    }];
    
let array = [28,13];

let resultado = Objeto.filter( item => array.includes(item.id));
console.log(resultado);

for(let item of resultado){
  console.log(item.name);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me he acercado mucho

Comment: @M47YOchO2 Si te sirvió, puedes marcarla como correcta